# Can't put website in iframe

Tags: html, iframe

I'm trying to put g2a.com website in an iframe, but it doesn't work. When I insert code below to my html file g2a website, it is opening full screen, and I have g2a.com in address bar. It is working with any other website I have tried so it has to be something specific about g2a.com. Anyone have an idea how to make it work with iframe?

```html
<iframe src="https://www.g2a.com/" width="50%" height="50%" frameborder="0" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0">
    <p>Click <a href="https://www.g2a.com/">here</a>! (Your browser does not support iframes)</p>
</iframe>
```

Comment: It works fine when I click run code snippet.

Comment: they could be restricting you.

Answer (score 2):

g2a.com uses a framebraker, to avoid using this site in an iframe..

you can still add a

```
sandbox="allow-scripts"
```

in your example:

```
<iframe src="https://www.g2a.com/" sandbox="allow-scripts" width="50%" height="50%" frameborder="0" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0">
        <p>Click <a href="https://www.g2a.com/">here</a>! (Your browser does not support iframes)</p>
    </iframe>
```

to your iframe, which works in most newer browsers. This prohibits that the website in the frame can affect the main window.